# Clearing memory in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I'm working on new WPF application. And I'm just wondering do I have to dispose or clear memory in any way in Views or View Models?

I only found information, that I should do it when using com ports or any external devices.

Comment: Dispose anything that is `IDisposable`.

Comment: How do I know what is IDisposable?

Comment: From the documentation. It's an implemented interface, e.g. `public abstract class Stream : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable`. I.e. every Stream should be disposed after usage (preferrably by putting it in a `using` block).

Comment: ok but what about Views or View Models? Do I have to dispose them as well, or close them when I don't use any Strem?

Comment: There's a bit more to it than just disposing everything.  Garbage collection works by scanning for un-rooted objects, and reclaiming the memory, at some arbitrary point in time.  You need to not hold on to references to things you no longer use.  Just a made up example: if you open a new Window and you store a reference to that window in a collection, if the user closes the window you need to remove it from your collection, otherwise that Window will never be garbage collected.  Typically, IDisposable is a nice pattern to use to do such things but it is not a magic wand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question, so it is hard to provide a specific answer. .NET applications are garbage collected, so in general things are cleaned up once you no longer reference them anywhere.

**Objects that Need Cleanup**

There are certain things that the garbage collector will not clean up for one reason or another. In the vast majority of these cases, the class you are working with will implement the [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface. The most common things that I run into that are disposable are streams and stream-related classes. However, it is a good idea to check anytime you are using something you are unsure about.

So when it comes to views and view models in WPF, the same rules apply. If you are using something that implements [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), then you need to either call `Dispose` on it when you are done, or wrap the creation of the object in a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block if it makes sense for the use case.

In some cases, a viewmodel might own an instance of a disposable object. In such a case, the viewmodel should itself implement [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), and ensure it disposes the object within its own `Dispose` method. You will then need to call `Dispose` on the viewmodel when you are done with it.

**Events**

A common source of memory leaks in .NET applications are event handlers. Once an application starts to have some complexity to it, you might find that a temporary object (like some viewmodels) will want to register for events with things that have a longer lifespan (such as a service or persistent utility). Registering an event handler using the `+=` operator creates a hidden reference from the event sending object to the event handling object. You will need to remove these handlers using the `-=` operator to allow the garbage collector to cleanup the handler and the object that owns it.

If you find yourself in a situation where you do not have a valid place to ensure an event is unregistered, consider using a [`WeakEventManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199438.aspx) to add the handler instead of the `+=` operator. This allows an object to handle events without the event sender having an explicit reference to the handling object. However, there is a *very small* amount of additional performance and memory overhead registering for events this way, so I would not recommend blindly switching all of your event handlers to weak events. Use it just where you need to.

Keep in mind that there are plenty of cases where not unregistering an event is ok and will not cause any memory leak. This is usually true when both the event sender and the event handler have the same life cycle, as is usually the case with a view and its associated view model. In such a case, it is fine for the view to register for events on the viewmodel and never unregister. As long as both the view and viewmodel stop being referenced by anything, they will get cleaned up regardless of the event that links them together.

**Summary**

There are no hard rules on whether views and viewmodels need any special handling to clean them up. If they are making use of a feature that requires special cleanup, then you will have to deal with that in whatever way is appropriate.

If you are not using any disposable objects, or other things that need explicit cleanup, then all you have to worry about is removing references to your views and viewmodels when you no longer need them.

If you want more technical information about the garbage collector, take a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx). Having an understanding of how it works may help you better understand when and how to clean things up.